# jquery catch a first keypress only?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
 $j("#regfname").keypress(function () {
    alert('Handler for .keypress() called.');
});
```

and want to execute only once... or only for the first keypress ..what's the most optimal way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - check if first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538937/jquery-check-if-first-click)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one#typedatafn) method to only execute the event once per element.

```
$j("#regfname").one("keypress", function () {
    alert('Handler for .keypress() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function:

```
$j('#regfname').one('keypress', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").one("keypress", function () {......});
```