# How use the one method on dynamic content? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I would like to detect when a user has pressed a key in a contenteditable div. However, the div is loaded dynamically and I would only like catch the first key press.

I would like the same outcome as [jquery catch a first keypress only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891678/jquery-catch-a-first-keypress-only) but for dynamic content.

My code so far:

```
$(document).on('keypress',"#divid",function(){});
```

Comment: Just change .on( to .one(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to catch the first keypress, you can use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) for that (yes, really `one` — it's a horrible pun):

```
$(document).one('keypress',"#divid",function() { });
```

Or explicitly remove the handler when it's fired (perhaps after checking some condition):

```
$(document).on('keypress',"#divid",handler);

function handler() {
    $(document).off('keypress',"#divid");
}
```

(Yes, heaven help us, the function is really called [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).)

Comment: Why not use .one()? you're just re-implementing its logic here? Who said it is going away?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Overlapping comment and edit, I'd misread the docs and there *is* a version of it that supports event delegation. :-)

Comment: Great:) you got be worried, I use it in production code a lot.

Comment: If it's included in 1.9, it'l be included in 2.0. 2.0 isn't losing any methods, it's just losing oldIE support to gain performance enhancements. The api between 1.9 and 2.0 should be identical.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: [This blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/) from June says that the goal is for 1.9 and 2.0 to have the same API. Since 1.9 is out, and `one` is *not* marked deprecated in the API docs, I think that was my brain being addled.

Comment: @KevinB: Wow, what timing, we posted comments almost simultaneously saying the same thing. Four seconds apart, sez here. :-)