# jQuery - check if first click

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have 2 functions (A and B) called on a single div click. I need to call function A only on first click and function B whenever it is clicked. How could I do this?

Comment: you can use `.ond('click', A)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much simpler solution:

```
$('element').one('click',function(){
// Call A
}).click(function(){
// Call B
});
```

Comment: Except B will always be called

Comment: That's what OP wants @adeneo. He wants A to be called only once and B whenever it is clicked

Comment: indeed, this is exactly what OP asked for!

Comment: Well okay then, I probably misunderstood !

Comment: @adeneo, it happens ;)

Comment: @adeneo that's what OP wants

Comment: @Claudiu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538937/jquery-check-if-first-click/22539012#comment-34300665

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** for your first function and `.click()` as usual for your second function:

```
function a() {
    console.log('Fire once!');
}

function b() {
    console.log('Always fired!');
}

$('span').one('click', function() {
    a();    
});

$('span').click(function() {
    b();    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeqcZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add the first function on page load, that way that function gets called with the first click, at the end of the function you use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the first function and then assign the second one.

```
$(function(){
    $("selector").on("click",FunctionA);
});

function FunctionA(){
    /*Do stuff*/
    $(this).off("click");
    $(this).on("click",FunctionB);
}
```

Comment: This won't run `functionB` until the 2nd click. He said it should run on all clicks.